# javascript - very simple code, yet function is not defined

Tags: javascript

I've looked around on SO for a while now (probably an hour was spent searching) but I can't find a clear answer for my case. As far as I know, I'm not using jQuery or AJAX, only plain JavaScript. Here's how it looks like:

```js
var i;

var displayimg = document.getElementsById("displayimg"); // I'm not sure what I'm doing here. I thought that the onclick event might be in the wrong scope, so I tried setting it from JavaScript instead. It didn't work.
var imgb = document.getElementsByClassName("imgb");
for (i = 0; i < imgb.length; i += 1) {
    imgb[i].addEventListener("click", setSlide(i));
    console.log("successful");
}

var maxIndex;
var minIndex;

function startSlide(max, min) { // this function comes from the html body onload.
    "use strict";
    maxIndex = max;
    minIndex = min;
    showSlide(1);
}

function setSlide(n) { // this function comes from the .imgb buttons.
    "use strict";
    showSlide(n);
    console.log("OK");
}

function showSlide(n) {
    "use strict";
    if (n > maxIndex) {
        n = minIndex;
    } // if number exceeds 3, go back to 1 (top)
    if (n < minIndex) {
        n = maxIndex;
    } // if number deceeds 1, go back to 3 (bottom)
    for (i = 0; i < imgb.length; i += 1) { // loops through all imgb
        imgb[i].className = imgb[i].className.replace(" active", ""); // removes active class from all imgb
    }
    document.getElementsById("displayimg").style["background-image"] = "url('pre".concat(i, ".png')");
    imgb[n - 1].className += " active";
    console.log("slide updated");
}
```

```html
<div id="displayimg" style="background-image:url('pre1.png');"></div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <span class="imgb"></span>
    <span class="imgb"></span>
    <span class="imgb"></span>
</div>
```

I might have messed up the script, I looked at a lot of tutorials and answers in SO and kind of just mashed them together hoping it would work. It seems that a recurring problem is the "out of scope" thing when I try to run it through JSLint, as well as every "for" loop being unexpected.
This problem has broken me. I feel like I'm stuck in a tedious loop of unsolved problems rising every time I try a new solution. Please, any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is `document.getElementById` not `document.getElementsById`.

Comment: and also `("click", setSlide(i));` <-- wrong because you are calling it not assigning it.

Comment: "*kind of just mashed them together hoping it would work*" and now you want us to fix it?  What have you actually tried?  What does your debugger say?  You haven't listed any steps that you have taken to try and resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written `.getElementsById()`, but the correct name is `.getElementById()` and your `click` callback function is not defined correctly - - the way you have it, the function will be called immediately. It needs to be wrapped in another function.

Also, don't use the same loop counter (`i`) across multiple callbacks as a closure will be formed that will cause problems with `i` being shared in multiple function executions.

Beyond that, it's generally better not to use `getElementsByClassName()` and instead use `.querySelectorAll()`, because the former returns a "live node list", which can be more resource intensive than the latter. Additionally, if you convert the node list returned by `.querySelectorAll()` into an Array, you can take advantage of the `Array.forEach()` method, which allows you to loop over the array without the need for a loop counter at all.

```js
var displayimg = document.getElementById("displayimg"); 

// If we turn the node list returned here into a proper Array, we don't need a loop counter
var imgb = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".imgb"));

imgb.forEach(function(el, idx){
    el.addEventListener("click", function(){
      setSlide(idx);
    });
    console.log("successful");
});

var maxIndex;
var minIndex;

function startSlide(max, min) { // this function comes from the html body onload.
    "use strict";
    maxIndex = max;
    minIndex = min;
    showSlide(1);
}

function setSlide(n) { // this function comes from the .imgb buttons.
    "use strict";
    showSlide(n);
    console.log("OK");
}

function showSlide(n) {
    "use strict";
    if (n > maxIndex) {
        n = minIndex;
    } // if number exceeds 3, go back to 1 (top)
    if (n < minIndex) {
        n = maxIndex;
    } // if number deceeds 1, go back to 3 (bottom)
    imgb.forEach(function(el, idx){ // loops through all imgb
        el.className = el.classList.remove("active"); // removes active class from all imgb
    });
    document.getElementById("displayimg").style["background-image"] = "url('pre".concat(i, ".png')");
    imgb[n - 1].className += " active";
    console.log("slide updated");
}
```

```html
<div id="displayimg" style="background-image:url('pre1.png');"></div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <span class="imgb"></span>
    <span class="imgb"></span>
    <span class="imgb"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: And that is still wrong. You have the infamous for loop. And multiple things use the same global variable `i`

Comment: That's still wrong. You're reusing the same `i` across all click handlers.

Comment: @epascarello Updated answer.